# Why does lsyncd require xnu?

Tags: macos, compilation, synchronization, fsevents, xnu

I am working through the steps of compiling lsyncd on Mac OS X (10.7.3 to be exact).

Finally managed to it get it compiled despite a couple minor syntax errors in the lysncd source code; and I understand from Axel Kittenberger (the developer managing lsyncd) that the compilation requires XNU.

References:-

- http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1073/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU

The configure step was done this way:-

```
./configure --without-inotify --with-fsevents CFLAGS="-I /Users/calvin/xnu-1699.24.23/" LUA_CFLAGS="-I /opt/local/include" LUA_LIBS="/opt/local/lib/liblua.a"
```

followed by some minor changes to the newly created Makefile (relating changing the path to asciidoc to my macports asciidoc location) and running

```
make
```

So all goes well and I finally have the resulting `lsyncd` binary.

**My question is: why was xnu required in this process?** (am curious to know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via Axel Kittenberger, author/maintainer of lsyncd, this is because:-

> Lsyncd accesses /dev/fsevents on a level that apple considers
> internal. Lsyncds event source on OSX was based on this code:
> [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200502165655/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/)